# How to print pixels of an image as a matrix?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, pixel

I would like to print the pixels of an image as a matrix.

Here is the code I am using:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("8Black.png")
pixels = list(im.getdata())

print(pixels)
```

I created the image "8Black.png" using photoshop and painted it all black. The python version that I use is 3.5.0. However, when I run the above code I get:

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,...,0]
```

I want to get this instead:

```
[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[...],[...]]
```

I tried changing this:

```
pixels = list(im.getdata())
```

to this:

```
pixels = np.matrix(im.getdata())
```

but still did not get the result I wanted.

How can I get the pixel data as a matrix? Did I miss something?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI - thank you for editing my question. I am sorry, I am not good in English.

Comment: No problem. Welcome to Stack Overflow, by the way :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're explicitely asking for the original 2D image to be "flattened" into a 1D sequence by doing `getdata()`.

You could use `reshape` to bring it back to it's original form

```
matrix = np.array(im.getdata()).reshape(im.size)
```